# Prevent idle spinning in logger thread

Tags: c++, computer-science

My program shares a very long list of files (provided by user) among 4 worker threads. Each worker logs to a simple vector (logPool). Since workers are very busy, I chose to make the logger spin constantly. Here is the sequential version :

```
struct logRec{ enum class type : unsigned { info = 0, error, end } typ;  /* end : marker for pool finalized, no-mo-msg */
               string msg; };
auto static const INFO = logRec::type::info, ERROR = logRec::type::error, END = logRec::type::end;
typedef vector<struct logRec> logPool;
vector<logPool> logPools;

//Print out log pools in order
void logger(){
  
  constexpr auto prLog = [](const size_t iPool, const size_t k) -> bool /*end reached ?*/ {
    switch(const auto& lrec = logPools[iPool][k]; lrec.typ){
      case INFO  : cout <<       lrec.msg      <<"\n"  <<std::flush; return false;
      case ERROR : cerr <<"\n"<< lrec.msg      <<"\n\n"<<std::flush; return false;
      [[unlikely]] case END : return true;
    }
    return true;
  };
  
  size_t last = 0, k = 0; bool end = false;
  for(auto i=0; i<logPools.size(); i++){ // sequential mode
    last = k = 0; end = false;
    while(!end){  // keep scanning pool #i until an end marker is reached
      for(k = last; k < logPools[i].size(); k++) if((end = prLog(i,k))) break;
      last = k;
    }
  }
}
```

There is no synchronisation with logger thread : workers don't know it exists, which makes for very straightforward code.

On the other hand, all the time spent by workers initializing/processing a large file/.. is spent spinning by the logger (waste of resources).

Is there a better way ? (like signalling the logger every 1000 log records/300ms or so..)

(the non-sequential version which visits all log pools in each loop is much less likely to come up empty-handed, so almost never spins idly)

Comment: This code reads data that's written by another thread.  Synchronization is a hard requirement.  Google "c++ reader writer lock" to get ahead.

Comment: Yes. No explicit synchronization is needed though. Updating a `size_t` is atomic (logPool.size). The signal is "size changed".

Comment: @WasfiJAOUAD Synchronization _is_ needed. Understanding that is a prerequisite to any progress on the implementation. First, no assumptions should be made about `std::vector::size()` being “atomic”, which has nothing to do with `size_t` being “atomic” (in the sense of value consistency, not in the sense of automatic synchronization of access). The documentation makes it abundantly clear what is or isn’t thread-safe (for parallel reads vs writes) in STL containers. There is absolutely no protection against `std::vector`s reallocating under `operator[]`’s hands etc.

Comment: I understand. No, there is no *need* for any synchronization *here*. There is no cooperation with workers. The worst that can happen is reading an old value of `size` and missing a few records at the end of the vector, next loop will take care of that + the end marker. There is *no* bug in this logger (as a matter of fact, this code processed tens of millions of files over the years, without a glitch). Yes, I'm asking about an possible alternative where, in case of cooperation, there will be need for synchronization.

Comment: @WasfiJAOUAD Nope. Still wrong. What _does_ (and not just _can_) happen here is _undefined behavior_. Getting an outdated `size()` is the smallest problem. The `vector` may have reallocated its storage buffer while `operator[]` is accessing memory where the old buffer was. This is undefined behavior and a random crash waiting to happen. This kind of setup might “work” a thousand times (or tens of millions of times), but then fail unexpectedly. Claiming that there is _no bug_ in this logger is simply a misunderstanding of both STL and broader synchronization concepts; sorry to say that.

Comment: W.r.t. what the possible alternative would be: A properly synchronized queuing mechanism. It doesn’t have to block loggers. There are properly implemented non-blocking queues (and even trees and hash tables) out there. A (somewhat) blocking possibility easy to read and implement may be a “ring buffer” of logging vectors controlled by a semaphore-like primitive to keep readers and writers safely apart. Log writers would use the non-blocking “side”, the logger thread would use the blocking “side”. Using STL incorrectly and hoping for the best is a bad idea; hope is not a strategy.

Comment: @Andrej Podzimek : my bad, I failed to mention the fact that the vectors are all pre-allocated (`reserve()`d) beforehand (since their extent is known = as many files a worker gets). No reallocations.

Comment: Pre-allocated vectors remove the need for *access* synchronization, what I need then is to put the logger to sleep (instead of spinning frantically) until there is something to log (this info is with the workers). This is a (cheap?)wait / wakeup mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me : signaling through a condition variable

```cpp
condition_variable logCV;
size_t logEvery = 1200; // every n files
auto logBreak = 1200ms; // scaled to work chunk size in main()
std::atomic<bool> threads_done{ false };

auto logger() noexcept -> void {
  
  constexpr auto prLog = [](const logRec& lrec) -> bool /*end reached ?*/ {
    switch(lrec.typ){
      case LOG_INFO  : cout <<       lrec.msg <<"\n"  ; return false;
      case LOG_ERROR : cerr <<"\n"<< lrec.msg <<"\n\n"; return false;
      [[unlikely]] case LOG_END : return true;
    }
    std::unreachable();
  };
  
  auto lk = unique_lock<mutex>( *(new mutex) );

  size_t sz = 0, last = 0, k = 0; bool end = false;
  for(auto i=0; i<logPools.size(); i++){ // sequential mode

    last = k = 0; end = false;
    while(!end){  // keep scanning pool #i until an end marker is reached
      last = k;
      if(not threads_done) logCV.wait_for(lk,logBreak); // coffee break
      // if threads are all done, you're behind buddy, speed through logPools, no waiting
      sz = logPools[i].size();
      if(sz==last and logPools[i][sz-1].typ == LOG_END) break;
      for(k = last; k < sz; k++) if( (end = prLog(logPools[i][k])) ) break;
      std::fflush(stdout); std::fflush(stderr);
    }

  }
}

void worker(){
  // std::lock_guard ; pick a work chunk, if any are left
  size_t done = 0;
  for(auto& file : workChunk) {
    // process file
    done++;
    if(done % logEvery == 0) logCV.notify_one();
  }
}

main(){
  ...
  // Run threads
  threads_done = true;
  ...
}
```

Tested with excellent performance on populations up to 60k work items.